# Расширить маску SVG без stretching?

Tags: html, css, svg

Я пытаюсь создать эффект «источника света» в SVG, посредством чего вырезаю часть темной области, которая будет перекрывать изображение.

Я почти получил то, что мне нужно, но я  пытаюсь понять, как закончить последнюю часть. Сначала вот мой пример:

```css
.background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.light {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
      <radialGradient id="radGrad">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
      </radialGradient>
      <mask id="hole">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="black"></rect>
        <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="155" fill="url(#radGrad)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect class="light" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#hole)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

То, что я хочу сделать сейчас, - это растянуть черную заливку на остальную часть `SVG`, но при этом сохранить радиальный градиент.

Я просто не могу понять, как это сделать. Фактически, дополнительный `<rect>` внутри `<mask>`, который я забыл удалить, является моей попыткой реализовать это.

Эффект, который я пытаюсь получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но до сих пор ближайший градиент у меня есть, который увеличивает радиус круга, и при этом увеличивается область прозрачности, это не совсем то, что я хочу получить, как на рисунке выше.

Я упускаю что-то очень простое?

Перевод вопроса:   [Extend SVG Mask without stretching? @Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43355198/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355198/extend-svg-mask-without-stretching/43367352#43367352

Answer (score 1):

Просто примените градиент к прямоугольнику. Нет необходимости в дополнительном круге.

Вам  нужно немного изменить свой градиент.

```css
.background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.light {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
      <radialGradient id="radGrad" r="0.31">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="black" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" />
      </radialGradient>
      <mask id="hole">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="url(#radGrad)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect class="light" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#hole)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Extend SVG Mask without stretching? @Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43367352/7394871)